# onmouseup not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, onmouseup, onmouseclick

This is the example which I got from w3schools, where I am getting weird behaviour for safari browser alone.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousedown

**Safari:**
If we left-click on top of paragraph, the text turns red color and when I leave it , it turns Green color.
That's fine.
Now, I am right-clicking on top of the paragraph.Now the text color turns Red and when I leave it, it NEVER turns to green color. i.e `onmouseup` is not working in safari if we are using right click. Can anyone tell me why ?
Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In safari, it seems like the focus is given to the context menu when right-clicking, so the context menu receives the mouseup event rather than the P element. As for a solution, you can detect the mouse button to prevent it to behave on the right click. Right click events are 
messy unless you want to handle a custom context menu.

If you want the mouseup event to work in safari when fired with a right click, you will need to disable the context menu by adding this attribute to the P element:

```
oncontextmenu="return false">
```

It is also possible to detect if the left click fired the event (which is usually the button you want to handle):

```
function mouse_handler(event) {
    var evt=window.event||event;
    var button = evt.which || evt.button;
    if (button == 1) { // if left mouse button
        // handle the event
    }
}
```

In the example from w3schools, it would lead to something like this:

```
function myFunction(elmnt,clr,event)
{
    var evt=window.event||event;
    var button = evt.which || evt.button;
    if (button == 1) { // if left mouse button
        elmnt.style.color=clr;
    }
}
```

Then passing the event in the function call:

```
<p onmousedown="myFunction(this,'red',event)" onmouseup="myFunction(this,'green',event)">
```

Comment: Oh no. Sorry. You have mistaken me. I don't want to disable to onmouseup and onmousedown for right-click. I want to trigger onmouseup for safari browsers

Comment: Actually, I am using context menus. So user directly right clicks on top of textbox. So I want to trigger onmouseup when the user right clicks textbox. Though I used onfocus,it is not returning the exact values I need

Comment: I think you will have an hard time fighting with safari's default behavior as well as some other browsers as if the element doesn't receive the event (ie: when context menu gets the focus), it just cannot be handled. You may need to sacrifice the context menu or the right click interactions.

Comment: am almost crying. Planning to use onmousedown

Comment: In my opinion, users are used to right click only when they need to access the context menu so there's no big deal if it doesn't interact with the ui. I fail to think of a case in which both default context menu and custom interaction are really needed. It's my opinion though.